# How to open a submenu when clicking on a top level link in jQuery SmartMenus

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

I am using jquery smartmenus for a website, the plugin by default displays submenus when the user hovers the parent item, however, my parent items have no content and clicking on them should open the submenu in the same way it displays when I hover.

I had a look at their website http://vadikom.github.io/smartmenus/src/demo/ but I am finding difficult to find what I am after.

Has anyone done this before? I was expecting to find a parameter I can pass, but I am lost here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Refer to http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/

> **showOnClick** Type: Boolean
>   Determines whether to show the first-level sub menus onclick instead of onmouseover - i.e. like drop-down menus on desktop applications. This option matters only for mouse input.

**Usage:**

```
<!-- SmartMenus jQuery init -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus({
            subMenusSubOffsetX: 1,
            subMenusSubOffsetY: -8,
            showOnClick:true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that was the question. If I understand correctly, webmedia wants the menu to not actually fire a click event when an item that has a submenu is clicked.

He/she wants instead, for the submenu to show when an item is clicked as well as it to show when hovered. If you set the showOnClick:true, this will not show submenus on hovering.

I have a similar issue in that I do not want any action when a menu item is clicked, but ONLY if it has a submenu(s). How I achieve this is by getting the item value/text and all items that have a submenu begin with the + character, so I ignore them and everything else I process. The hover still displays the submenu.